# How to draw shapes with curved sides with python ImageDraw

Tags: python-3.x

How do I draw a polygon with curved(convex, concave, circular, whatever you call it) sides? For example very simple triangles like in this picture:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/70HAn.jpg

I know the formula for arcs, polygons, ellipses etc., but not sure about this one .

Comment: have you tried something for it?

Comment: Just want to add that we use Pillow and not turtle... If no answers come up I guess I'd probably have to start doing 20-side polygons....